# Interfacing a microcontroller to a PDM microphone via DMA and low power

Tags: microcontroller, adc, low-power, sound, dma

I need to interface a low power PDM microphone ([Vesper VM1010](https://vespermems.com/products/vm1010/)) to a low power microcontroller with ZigBee support.  For the latter, I've settled on [Silicon Labs EFM32 Gecko](https://www.silabs.com/mcu/32-bit-microcontrollers/efm32-gecko), primarily due to its thorough docs and sample code.  However, the Gecko doesn't seem to have a PDM interface.

I could simply use the GPIO and convert PDM in software.  This would be great except for power: I want to capture the audio via DMA and keep the CPU not in full power.

What options are there for me to capture the PDM while still maintaining low power?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply convert PDM to analog using an appropriate analog low-pass filter on the PDM signal. You can then sample that with the ADC of your microcontroller (it probably has one, and if it does, that probably also is DMA-capable).

Alternatively, you can also implement the the low pass filtering in software using a shift register (e.g. from an SPI module) and 1-bit-count as instantaneous value.

**However**, the [datasheet of the VM1010](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/960/vesper_tech_06182019_VM1010-1605563.pdf) says it's not a PDM microphone at all. You can hence only do one thing: directly sample its analog output.

Comment: Thank you.  For my knowledge, by "using an appropriate analog low-pass filter," you mean a discrete analog filter, not on the MCU, yes? And won't "implement the the low pass filtering in software using a shift register" force the CPU to be fully awake whenever receiving audio (otherwise, a 3 MHz PDM would quickly fill the buffer).

Comment: yes, as said, an analog filter.

Comment: again, the microphone you have chosen is not a PDM microphone.

Comment: and sure, it'll be quick to fill the buffer, but you want to do something with the samples, anyway, so that's not a problem you're getting rid of any way.

Comment: Re "but you want to do something with the samples, anyway, so that's not a problem you're getting rid of any way": I'd like to batch the processing to conserve battery

Comment: but the data rate stays the same, as the number of samples per second that you need to take is the same (Nyquist). There's no free lunch here.